# How to index MongoDB collection in Perl?

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have indexed my MongoDB collection by field name using following command in Mongo command prompt.

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({"name" : 1})
```

Now I am trying to do this exact same command in Perl. 
I tried

```
$mycollection->ensureIndex({"name" : 1});
```

Not working.

Comment: For those looking at this question post-hoc, note that ensureIndex has been depreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here: [MongoDB::Examples](https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB%3a%3aExamples).
Another great place to find MongoDB driver is: [MongoDB::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB%3a%3aTutorial).

These 2 pages seem to have the most examples I look for on MongoDB Perl driver.

This is the correct syntax below

```
$mycollection->ensure_index({"name" => 1});
```

BTW indexing sped up my find so much. It took 1 second to retrieve 1 record from few million record now after indexing
it takes 1 second to read 10K record from a few million record. so that is huge improvement for me.